# MySql как составить правильныый запрос

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, запрос

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть такое представление базы данных
Необходимо написать запрос, который находит сколько раз между собой играли команды. Важно, если команда А играла против команды В, а затем команда В играла против команды А, то это считается как одно и тоже событие. То есть, результат должен быть следующим: А против В - 2 игры.  Неполный результат запроса представлен на рисунке

```
SELECT least(home_team, away_team) AS A, greatest(home_team, away_team) AS B, COUNT(*) as 
games_count
FROM event_entity
GROUP BY A , B
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1                        
ORDER BY A, B
```

Но не получаю вот такого вывода как его можно реализовать ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой запрос даст нужный результат:

```
SELECT e.participants, count(*) AS games_count
FROM (SELECT concat(least(home_team, away_team), greatest(home_team, away_team)) AS participants
FROM event_entity) AS e
GROUP BY participants
```

Comment: Не могу получить 1-цу в game_count. В своем запросе так-же не могу этого добится.

Comment: что имеете в виду под единицей?

Comment: как в скриншоте в выводе games_count 1, такого значения у меня нету.

Comment: может быть в ваших исходных данных все команды сыграли друг с другом больше одного раза?

Comment: Скриншот который я приложил является частью вывода который я должен получить, так что там они должны сыграть 1 раз)

Comment: покажите исходные данные таблицы event_entity

Comment: вот пример http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c1232f/1/0

Comment: Пример данных: (1,'football','KRC Genk','Beerschot AC'),(2,'football','SV Zulte-Waregem','Sporting Lokeren'),(3,'football','KSV Cercle Brugge','RSC Anderlecht')

Comment: пожалуйста пример с вашими данными http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a73dd0/1/0

Comment: Все так же не могу получить эту 1-цу, спасибо вам, может подскажете хоть как их отсортировать по возрастанию кол-ва игр ?

Comment: order by games_count

Comment: Спасибо огромное очень помогли !